# Create Document Set In Document Library Using CSOM : SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, document-set

I am trying to create `Document Set` in `Document Library`. I found [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-document-set-using-csom-in-sharepoint-2013) code which is for SharePoint 2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet;

namespace CSOMSamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //// String Variable to store the siteURL
            string siteURL = "Site URL";

            //// String Variable to store the document set name
            string dsName = "DS Name";

            //// Get the context for the SharePoint Site to access the data
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

            //// Get the document library in which the document set has to be created
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            //// Get the parent folder where the document set has to be created
            Folder parentFolder = list.RootFolder;

            //// Get the "Document Set" content type by id (Document Set content type Id : 0x0120D520) for the document library
            ContentType ct = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0120D520");
            clientContext.Load(ct);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //// Create a new document set
            //// A new document set will be created in "Documents" library as "Vijai Documents" under which you can add the documents
            DocumentSet.Create(clientContext, parentFolder, dsName, ct.Id);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

While running this code I got following error

> Cannot find proxy for type with id
>   "{e32a87f7-b866-407d-971d-027ed940d50f}"

So my question is Does any one else gone through the same requirement for creating `Document Set` in `Document Library` using CSOM in SP 2010 then please provide some of useful guideline.

I already gone through [this](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-your-sharepoint-2010.html) and [this](https://praveenkasireddy.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/create-document-set-and-upload-file-using-client-object-model-om/) and [this](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-create-document-set-remotely.html) but found no useful.

Comment: I have not done that before, but are you100% sure you are using the right .dll for DocumentSet. Seen that kinda error before, and then I have used 2013 version against 2010 server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally with the help of code given in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71788/bug-2010-document-sets-via-client-model-shown-as-folder) post I was able to achieve the task. The code which I used is:

```
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, siteURL);
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
clientContext.Credentials = creds;
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLibrary1");
ContentTypeCollection listContentTypes = list.ContentTypes;
clientContext.Load(listContentTypes, types => types.Include(type => type.Id, type => type.Name, type => type.Parent));
var result = clientContext.LoadQuery(listContentTypes.Where(c => c.Name == "Document Set"));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ContentType targetDocumentSetContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();
ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
newItemInfo.LeafName = "Document Set1";
//newItemInfo.FolderUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);
newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();
newListItem.Update();
list.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code worked successfully. This is not the only solution. If any one have any other approach then they are welcome to help.